# Template Literal apparently not interpreted (but it is!)

Tags: template-literals

This code demonstrates the interpretation of a template literal but apparently it hasn't been interpreted when applied to the button's onclick property. But it still works, how?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" id = "B">Click</button>
<script>
Click("Hello World!");
function Click(Message)
{
   document.getElementById("B").onclick = function(){ShowAlert(event, `${Message}`);};
}
function ShowAlert(e, Message)
{
   alert(e.target.onclick + "\n" + Message);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why has `${Message}` apparently not been interpreted?

Comment: [Here's a list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#browser_compatibility) of browsers supporting it. Are you using an older browser?

Comment: I am up to date. The question is why the button.onclick property is showing the uninterpreted literal but clicking it actually shows the interpreted value.

I'm trying to debug a more complex situation but can't examine the onclick property because of this anomaly.